# call function when image src changes

Tags: jquery

I'm attempting to call a function whenever images with a specific class loads. The point is to generate a carousel gallery of thumbnails below a slideshow of bigger images with captions, etc.

I've tried using both on.('changed' .. ) and on.('load' .. ) to no avail, I have tried binding events to the changes in the dom. I have tried the simplest of all solutions by just using the click function on the buttons that switches the slideshows images. The only result I end up with is the old src attribute so my carousel is always one step behind the gallery.

How do I call a function when an image has a new src?

Update with what I have tried so far to call the function:

```
jQuery('.nivo-main-image').on('load', function() {
    makegallery();
});

jQuery('.nivo-main-image').load( function() {
    makegallery();    
});

jQuery('.nivo-main-image').attr('src' function() {
    makegallery();    
});
```

jQuery('#container').change(function(){ makegallery(); });  // The containing div

Comment: It's difficult to offer help without any code.  A jsFiddle is always ideal.

Comment: Images don't just get a new src by themselves. Can't you call your function in the place where you change it?

Comment: You'll need to post your HTML and Javascript in order for anyone to be able to help you.

Comment: Why not something like: `$('yourimageselector').attr('src', 'newsrc').load(function(){`

Comment: astex - I have updated my quesetion with examples of what I have tried to use to call the function. The image has a class of nivo-main-image

GolezTrol - I could and this is a valid point, I was looking for a quick fix as I'm attaching this gallery to a third-party slideshow and I was hoping not to have to modify their code. Thus just listen for events of the slideshow updating.

tymeJV - As above, the function of changing the images in the slideshow is done by a third party and I would rather not alter their code.

Comment: I was able to solve this by modifying the nivo slider plugin as GolezTrol suggested.

Thank you all for taking your time in helping with this.

Answer (score -1):

You can just use the load event.

http://jsfiddle.net/EkYpY/1/

```
$("img").on("load", function () {
    alert('loaded');
});
setTimeout(function () {
    $("img").attr("src", "http://images2.fanpop.com/images/photos/5700000/Random-random-5719763-1280-800.jpg");

}, 3000);
```

Here the image starts with one src.  Then when it changes the event fires.

Comment: Thank you but this code does not work, when is setTimeout called?

Comment: The settimeout is just there to change the src of the image.  To show you that the load event is firing.  How are you changing the src in your code?

Comment: The problem is that the the load event is not fired when the src changes. The src is changed by the nivo slider plugin so I'm not entirely certain to be honest. However I did find a function in the plugin that was called after the next slider image was loaded so I inserted my function call into that and it solved it.

Does however not answer the question of how one DOES trigger an event from an image src change, maybe it's just not possible?